# Start jboss windows service to be visible from outside

Tags: java, service, windows-services, jboss

I've managed to setup jboss as windows service found this article http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/install/service.html

When I try it localhost:8080/ it works, but when I try to access it from another computer I can't open it.

When I'm setuping jboss in eclipse I usually pass argument -b 0.0.0.0 and it works from outside, how can I do it for this windows service? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this in the past by specifying the argument explicitly in the service.bat file.

You should see where the call to **run.bat** is made in the service.bat file, and at that point you can add the **-b 0.0.0.0** argument

```
call run.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a windows installation handy, but I think you just have to edit run.bat to add the -b 0.0.0.0 program argument, and then rerun the program that generates the JBoss service. Could you post the contents of run.bat?

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through `service.bat` and found

```
:cmdStart
REM Executed on service start
del .r.lock 2>&1 | findstr /C:"being used" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
  echo Could not continue. Locking file already in use.
  goto cmdEnd
)
echo Y > .r.lock
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Starting %SVCDISP%" > run.log
call run.bat -b 0.0.0 .0< .r.lock >> run.log 2>&1
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Shutdown %SVCDISP% service" >> run.log
del .r.lock
goto cmdEnd
```

Edit `call run.bat< .r.lock >> run.log 2>&1`

to

```
call run.bat -b 0.0.0.0 < .r.lock >> run.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see where the call to run.bat is made in the service.bat file, and at that point you can add the -b 0.0.0.0 argument

Remember the service.bat file is located in jboss_home/bin. In my version, I had two lines that call "call run.bat < .r.lock >> run.log 2>&1", so I changed it for "call run.bat -b 192.xxx.xxx.xxx -c all < .r.lock >> run.log 2>&1" and it worked for me.

Hernan.